# Error when running projects on Expression Blend 4

Tags: expression-blend

Whenever I try to run a project on Expression Blend 4 an error always appear.

The specified solution configuration "Debug|MCD" is invalid.Please specify a valid solution configuration using the Configuration and Platform properties (e.g. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p Configuration=Debug / p:Platform="Any CPU" or leave those properties blank to use the default solution configuration )

In some forums I've read that by deleting something on the registry will solve this issue but what I want to know is if it's safe to do that or if there are other ways to solve this error.

Answer (score 4):

[It turns out that HP machines from the factory come with several global variables set for it’s own update software, including things such as “PCBRAND”. One of those variables are, you guessed it, PLATFORM.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brandonwerner/archive/2010/03/14/the-nasty-visual-studio-platform-mcd-error-in-visual-studio-2010-rc.aspx)

In VS 2010 RC the build environment started respecting “Platform” as a compile time System variable. Therefore, because no such platform exists in your deployment configuration, it fails.

It’s a pretty simple fix, just delete the PLATFORM variable.

***You need to do the following steps:***

- Right-mouse click "Computer"
- Go to "Properties"
- Click "Advanced System Settings"
- Click "Environment Variables"
- Under "System Variables" find "PLATFORM" and delete it.
- Restart Visual Studio

Here’s hoping I saved you some time.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean:

http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en/blend/thread/f664d317-2415-4369-b461-a22eb0a2f023

&

http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/blend/thread/71496590-a9ec-4e3a-8353-3ced345f78dc/#18af3654-2ee7-4e61-a1e1-321d430026eb

Then yes. It's to do with HP and the way they package up the extra applications on the machine. I found that the MCD platform key was in the registry in a few places, I deleted them and then restarted and now blend builds great.